# How to find a missing number from a string of digits without spaces between them?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

> **Input Format**
>
> The first line will contain the set of numbers in the sequence. Number
>   are listed in ascending order.
>
> **Boundary Conditions**
>
> 1<=M<=99999 Length of string S is from 5 to 200.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> The first line will contain the missing number M.
>
> **Example Input /Output 1**
>
> Input: 12346789
>
> Output: 5
>
> **Input /Output 2** Input  596597598600601602
>
> Output : 599
>
> The numbers a sequence in the sequence are 596 597 598 599 600 601
>   602. 599 is the missing numbers

My Java solution is:

I have used `split(("?<=\\G..."))`, etc., to split the numbers into one, two, three four and five digits. And saved the numbers into a corresponding array. Then I checked for any difference between two adjacent numbers in a array - if it is one then it will invoke a function to find the missing number.

But problem is that when:

**Input:**

```
999899991000110002
```

**Output :**

```
10000
```

the sequence is 9998 9999 10001 10002. The missing number is 10000

How would I split the string when a transition from a 4 digit to a 5 digit number is possible? Is there any better way of solving this problem?

```
public void test(Scanner in)
{
    String n = in.nextLine();
    int n1 = n.length();
    System.out.println(n1);
    if (n1 % 2 == 0)
    {

    } else {
      n = "0" + n;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    String[] one = n.split("(?<=\\G.)");
    String[] two = n.split("(?<=\\G..)");
    String[] three = n.split("(?<=\\G...)");
    String[] four = n.split("(?<=\\G....)");
    String[] five = n.split("(?<=\\G.....)");
    int x = one.length;
    int y = two.length;
    int z = three.length;
    int u = four.length;
    int v = five.length;
    int[] aa1 = new int [x];
    int[] aa2 = new int [y];
    int[] aa3 = new int [z];
    int[] aa4 = new int [u];
    int[] aa5 = new int [v];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        aa1[i] = Integer.parseInt(one[i]);
    }
    if (aa1[1] == aa1[3] - 2)
    {
        findmissing(aa1, x);          
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        aa2[i] = Integer.parseInt(two[i]);
    }
    if (aa2[1] == aa2[3] - 2)
    {
        findmissing(aa2, y);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        aa3[i] = Integer.parseInt(three[i]);
    }
    if (aa3[1] == aa3[3] - 2)
    {
        findmissing(aa3, z);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < u; i++)
    {
        aa4[i] = Integer.parseInt(four[i]);
    }
    if (aa4[1] == aa4[3] - 2)
    {
        findmissing(aa4, u);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
    {
        aa5[i] = Integer.parseInt(five[i]);
    }
    if (aa5[1] == aa5[3] - 2)
    {
        findmissing(aa5, v);
    }
    in.close();
}

public static void findmissing(int[] bb, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < value - 1; i++)
    {
        if (bb[i] == bb[i + 1] - 1)
        {

        } else {
            System.out.println(bb[i + 1] - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Example 1 seems off. Shouldn't the input be missing the 5? Otherwise it's an interesting logic problem. I'll bet that if you work this out on paper a bit, you'll come up with a decent solution. I have a sneaking suspicion that you're up to the task. If this were my task, I'd work out on paper examples of typical edge cases like you described above, from the most simple single digit cases to larger number cases.

Comment: Provide some code? It sounds like you are hard-coding each split (into 1,2,3,4,5 digits)? If so, doesn't this sound like a good condition for a loop from 1,2,3,4,5...n?

Comment: Writing your own split function would be the way to go. Here you can modify the number of digits as appropriate.

Comment: I assume that the numbers are listed *in order*? You don't actually say this.

Comment: perhaps instead of loading all the numbers into arrays right away you could try just reading one number at a time. Then you'll know what number is expected to be the next one and how many characters you will need. You'll need to restructure lots of code but it might help with these edge cases. ie: read 998, next expected number is 999 so read 3 characters and check, then the number is 999, next expected number is 1000 so read 4 characters and check. This does assume you know the first number though, I don't know it that will always be the case

Comment: Your code looks much too complex with much redundancy and use of magic numbers. I would try to divide and conquer, and would create simple methods that could be repeatedly called. Again, work things out on paper *first* before trying to commit to code.

Comment: @jdkorv11: You and I have basically the same idea.  To deal with not knowing the first number is actually easy: Just try them all! :)

Answer (score 1):

If (as I assume) the numbers are listed in order, then a very simple algorithm will work:

- For each possible digit-length 1 <= d <= 5 of the first number:

  - Call `try(toInt(S[1 .. d]), S[d+1 .. |S|])` to try the sequence of numbers beginning with the number encoded by S[1 .. d].  If this sequence "works", output it and stop.

The main loop above stops at d = 5 because you give the constraint that M <= 99999, but it can easily be made to work with arbitrarily large numbers, simply by letting d increase all the way up to |S|.

The second step ("Try...") is easy, since you already have the first number x in this (candidate) sequence, so you can easily generate the digit-string corresponding to the number that should appear next (i.e., corresponding to x+1) and compare it with the remainder of S.  If the digit-string corresponding to x+1 does not match the first few characters of S, then try the digit-string corresponding to x+2.  If that matches, then set a flag recording the fact that x+1 is potentially the missing number, and carry on.  If both x+1 and x+2 mismatch, or if x+1 mismatches and the flag is already set, we know that the initial value can't have been right, so return and let the main loop try the next longer initial number:

```
try(x, S):
    x1str = asString(x + 1)
    x2str = asString(x + 2)
    missing = -1        # Flag value to indicate "not found"
    while |S| >= |x1str|:
        if S[1 .. |x1str|] = x1str:
            Delete first |x1str| characters of S
            x = x + 1
            x1str = asString(x + 1)
            x2str = asString(x + 2)
        else if S[1 .. |x2str|] = x2str and missing = -1:
            Delete first |x2str| characters of S
            missing = x + 1
            x = x + 2
            x1str = asString(x + 1)
            x2str = asString(x + 2)
        else
            return -1    # Flag value to indicate "invalid sequence"
    if |S| > 0 then return -1    # Some gunk was left over
    return missing
```

Obviously you can replace the "Delete first ... characters of S" steps with just using an offset into the (unchanging) string, but I felt the above was easier for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive, runnable solution

```
public class FindGaps {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(gapFinder("12345789"));//6 expected
    System.out.println(gapFinder("99101"));//100 expected
    System.out.println(gapFinder("124126"));//123 expected
    System.out.println("fail expected: " + gapFinder("124125"));
    System.out.println("fail expected: " + gapFinder("123456A8"));
    System.out.println("fail expected: " + gapFinder("9910010210"));
    System.out.println("fail expected: " + gapFinder("10121416"));
  }

  public static int gapFinder(final String sequence) throws Exception {
    for (int digits = 1; digits <= sequence.length() / 2; digits++) {
      final Integer currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(sequence.substring(0, digits));
      final Integer ret = recursiveGapChecker(currentNumber + 1, sequence.substring(digits));
      if (ret != null && ret >= 0) {
        return ret;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  /**
   * @return null if the sequence is validated, the missing number if a gap is found, return<0 if the sequence is invalid
   */
  private static Integer recursiveGapChecker(final Integer nextNumber, final String remainder) {
    final String numAsString = nextNumber.toString();
    final int numLength = numAsString.length();
    final Integer numPlus1 = nextNumber + 1;
    final String numPlus1AsString = numPlus1.toString();
    final int numPlus1Length = numPlus1AsString.length();
    if (remainder.isEmpty()) {
      return null;//cleanly parsed the remainer
    } else if (remainder.length() < numLength) {
      return -1;//invalid length
    } else if (remainder.startsWith(numAsString)) {
      return recursiveGapChecker(nextNumber + 1, remainder.substring(numLength));
    } else if (remainder.startsWith(numPlus1AsString)) {
      Integer ret = recursiveGapChecker(numPlus1 + 1, remainder.substring(numPlus1Length));
      if (ret == null) {
        return nextNumber;//found it!
      } else if (ret < 0) {
        return -1;//problem parsing the rest of the string
      } else {
        return -2;//found more than one gap
      }
    } else {
      return -1;//the remainder doesn't match the given number
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is essentially my solution, but with iteration replaced with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you already know the first number to expect. Determining that first number could be tricky though.

```
public class SeqTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SeqTest().test("999899991000110002", 9998);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void test(String line, int nextExpectedNumber)
    {
        String remainingLine = line;
        boolean expected = true;
        Integer nextNumber = nextExpectedNumber;

        while (expected)
        {
            String expectedString = nextNumber.toString();

            if (!remainingLine.startsWith(expectedString))
            {
                expected = false;
                System.out.println("Missing " + expectedString + " from " + remainingLine);
            } else {
                // prune remainingLine
                remainingLine = remainingLine.substring(expectedString.length());
            }
            nextNumber = this.nextInSequence(nextNumber);
        }

        return;
    }

    public Integer nextInSequence(int current)
    {
        return ++current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to solving the problem that the OP gave, you have to solve two additional problems.

1. What happens when the numbers go from length to length + 1?
2. What happens when you have an initial pair of numbers that also work with a shorter length, like 9899 & 9900?  You can detect those numbers as 98, 99, 99, 00.

Anyway, here are the test cases that I ran against my code.  The first line is the number string.  The second line is the array of numbers from the string.  The third line is the missing number.

```
1234678910
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
5

26272829313233
[26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33]
30

9293949596979899101
[92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 101]
100

99101102103104105106107108109110111112
[99, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]
100

596597598600601602
[596, 597, 598, 600, 601, 602]
599

989999009901990299049905
[9899, 9900, 9901, 9902, 9904, 9905]
9903

98999901990299039904990599069907
[9899, 9901, 9902, 9903, 9904, 9905, 9906, 9907]
9900

9998999910000100011000210004
[9998, 9999, 10000, 10001, 10002, 10004]
10003
```

The point to be taken from this code is to try all of the edge cases you can think up.  I wouldn't have thought about the 9899, 9900 sequence unless I'd written the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MissingNumber implements Runnable {

    private String numberString;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MissingNumber missingNumber = new MissingNumber();
        missingNumber.setNumberString("1234678910");
        missingNumber.run();
        missingNumber.setNumberString("26272829313233");
        missingNumber.run();
        missingNumber.setNumberString("9293949596979899101");
        missingNumber.run();
        missingNumber.setNumberString("99101102103104105106107108109110111112");
        missingNumber.run();
        missingNumber.setNumberString("596597598600601602");
        missingNumber.run();
        missingNumber.setNumberString("989999009901990299049905");
        missingNumber.run();
        missingNumber.setNumberString("98999901990299039904990599069907");
        missingNumber.run();
        missingNumber.setNumberString("9998999910000100011000210004");
        missingNumber.run();
    }

    public void setNumberString(String numberString) {
        this.numberString = numberString;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(numberString);
        Integer[] numbers = getNumbers(numberString);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        int missingNumber = findMissingNumber(numbers);
        System.out.println(missingNumber + "\n");
    }

    private Integer[] getNumbers(String numberString) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 1;
        int length = 1;
        boolean isAdjacent = false;

        while (!isAdjacent) {
            Integer test1 = getSubstring(numberString, index1, length);
            Integer test2 = getSubstring(numberString, index2, length);
            Integer test3 = getSubstring(numberString, index2, length + 1);
            if (isValidDifference(test2, test1)) {
                numbers.add(test1);
                numbers.add(test2);
                try {
                    getRemainingNumbers(numberString, numbers, index2, length,
                            test2);
                    isAdjacent = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    numbers.clear();
                    length++;
                    index1 = 0;
                    index2 = index1 + length;
                }
            } else if (isValidDifference(test3, test1)) {
                numbers.add(test1);
                numbers.add(test3);
                length++;
                try {
                    getRemainingNumbers(numberString, numbers, index2, length,
                            test3);
                    isAdjacent = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    numbers.clear();
                    length++;
                    index1 = 0;
                    index2 = index1 + length;
                }
            } else {
                length++;
                index2 = index1 + length;
            }
        }

        return numbers.toArray(new Integer[numbers.size()]);
    }

    private void getRemainingNumbers(String numberString,
            List<Integer> numbers, int index2, int length, Integer previousTest)
            throws NumberFormatException {
        int index = index2 + length;
        while (index <= (numberString.length() - length)) {
            Integer test = getSubstring(numberString, index, length);
            if (isValidDifference(test, previousTest)) {
                numbers.add(test);
                previousTest = test;
                index += length;
            } else {
                length++;
            }
        }
    }

    private Integer getSubstring(String string, int index, int length)
            throws NumberFormatException {
        return Integer.valueOf(string.substring(index, index + length));
    }

    private boolean isValidDifference(int number2, int number1) {
        int diff = number2 - number1;
        return (diff == 1 || diff == 2);
    }

    private int findMissingNumber(Integer[] numbers) {
        int lastNumber = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int diff = numbers[i] - lastNumber;
            if (diff == 2) {
                return numbers[i] - 1;
            }
            lastNumber = numbers[i];
        }

        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can improve this code but try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pattern = "(\\d{%s})(\\d{0,%s})";
    String toVerify = "9979989991000100110021004";
    String toVerifyCopy = toVerify;

    List<Integer> items = new LinkedList<>();

    Integer found = null;

    for (int i = 1; i < toVerifyCopy.length(); i++) {
        int first = 0;
        Integer second = 0;

        int secondSize = i;
        boolean isSize = false;

        for (int j = 1; j < i + 2; j++) {
            Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(String.format(pattern, i, j));

            Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(toVerifyCopy);

            if (matcher.find()) {
                first = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                second = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));

                if (second == first + 1) {
                    secondSize = j;
                    isSize = true;

                    j++;
                } else if (second == first + 2) {
                    found = first + 1;
                    secondSize = j;

                    isSize = true;
                    j++;
                } else {
                    isSize = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isSize) {
            toVerifyCopy = toVerifyCopy.substring(i);
            i = i - 1;

            if (items.size() < 2 ||
                toVerifyCopy.length() == i + secondSize) {
                items.add(first);
            }

            items.add(second);
        } else {
            if (items.size() > 0) {
                if (first == items.get(items.size() - 1)) {
                    items.clear();

                    toVerifyCopy = toVerify;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (Integer item : items) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }

    if (found != null) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + found);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for a sequence, (3, 4, 6, 7) 
or              (13, 14, 16, 17) 
or              (113, 114, 116, 117)
```

you will always end up with last-first == sequence.size () // i.e. 7-3 = 4

So that way, it is easy to detect the right number length (at least reduce the list numbers to check significantly).

To improve performance, you may check, if String.length is divisible by number length, else a pitfall would be:

1230124 if you just pick the first 3 and last 3 characters, to test for number length 3.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberGap {

    static private boolean laengeFits (String numbers, int len, int start, int stop) {
        String front = numbers.substring (start, len);
        String back  = numbers.substring (stop - len, stop);
        // System.out.printf ("front - back = %s %s\n", front, back);
        int first = Integer.parseInt (front);
        int last  = Integer.parseInt (back);
        return (last - first == numbers.length () / len);
    }

    static private boolean isCandidate (String numbers, int len) {
        return (numbers.length() % len == 0 && laengeFits (numbers, len, 0, numbers.length ()));
    }

    static List <Integer> string2ints (String snum, int i) {
        List <Integer> vals = new ArrayList<> ();
        for (int n = 0; n < snum.length (); n+= i){
             String s = snum.substring (n, n+i);
             vals.add (Integer.parseInt (s));
        }
        return vals;
    }

    static private void findGap (String numbers) {
        System.out.printf ("\nSearching for: %s \n", numbers);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {
            if (isCandidate (numbers, i)) {
                List <Integer> vals = string2ints (numbers, i);
                // System.out.printf ("\telems: %d :\n", vals.size ());
                List <Integer> res = new ArrayList<> ();
                for (int j = 1; j < vals.size (); ++j) {
                    if (vals.get(j) != vals.get(j-1) + 1) {
                        res.add (vals.get(j-1) + 1);
                        if (res.size () > 1) {
                           System.out.printf ("Error multiple gaps: %d %d\n", res.get (0), res.get(1));
                           break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (res.size() == 1) {
                    System.out.printf (" * * *   Gap: %d   * * *\n", res.get (0));
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findGap ("012346789");
        findGap ("1234678910");
        findGap ("26272829313233");
        findGap ("26272829313333");
        findGap ("9293949596979899101");
        findGap ("99101102103104105106107108109110111112");
        findGap ("596597598600601602");
        findGap ("989999009901990299049905");
        findGap ("98999901990299039904990599069907");
        findGap ("9998999910000100011000210004");
    }
}
```

I first wrote a Scala solution, a one liner, admitting a pretty long line:

```
(1 to 5).map (i => {s.sliding (i, i)}.map (_.toInt).toVector).filter (v => (v(v.size - 1) - v(0) == v.size)).flatten .sliding (2, 1).filter {l => l(0) != l(1)-1}.map {l => l(1) -1}.mkString (":")
```

or better readable:

```
(1 to 5).map (i => {s.sliding (i, i)}.
    map (_.toInt).toVector).
    filter (v => (v(v.size - 1) - v(0) == v.size)).
    flatten.
    sliding (2, 1).
    filter {l => l(0) != l(1)-1}.
    map {l => l(1) -1}.mkString (":")
```

With s being the String to parse. The set of collection functions is more rich, not so much hassle, converting from Array to List or Vector, because a convenient function is only defined here, the other only there. Fluent conversion from int to Integer behind the scenes.